# Squid proxy: Ques about No cache and https transport

Tags: proxy

I have a Debian 10 VPS running squid. The only mods I made to the conf file were to allow my IP address to access it. It seems to run fine.
[1]
I want to turn off caching. My only reason for using squid is to change my apparent IP.
As a web developer, caching is a menace during the coding stage of development.

I have found various info on turning cache off but don't know exactly where to put it.

The wiki says:

```
You can use the cache access list to make Squid never cache any response:
cache deny all
```

But after hours of scrolling and searching the conf file I cannot find anything close to "cache access list".

A post on this forum says:

```
acl DIRECTORIES urlpath_regex ^/here/ ^/favicon.ico ^/there/
cache deny DIRECTORIES
cache deny all
```

Where exactly do I put these commands?

[2]
When my browser requests a page, perhaps from
https://amazon.com
Are the packets encrypted (SSL) leaving my site and traveling to the proxy?

Many thanks,
xstack

Comment: You put them into your Squid config, usually in `/etc/squid/squid.conf`. Read `man squid` on your system, you'll find the reference to the configuration location.

Comment: Hi AlexD. Thank you for response. I guess I have not been clear. Sorry. Yes I know about the 8,500 lines conf file. When I said above I have been searching and scrolling, I was referring to that squid.conf file in /etc/squid. I would not have squid running at all if I had not put my IP in that file. The BIG problem is WHERE within that file do I put the "no cache" command. The WIKI states that the order of reading the commands is important and emphasizes to put commands in exactly the correct place. Any ideas on this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of commands is important if you have interdependent commands or the same command with different ACLs like the following:

```
cache deny that
cache allow this
cache deny all
```

If you want to deny caching for everything, you can just add a single `cache deny all` anywhere in the file but make sure that there are no other `cache` directives. If you don't want to search then add it at the end of the file but you can miss some `cache allow` in the file.

Comment: Thanks again Alex. I used Regex search ^cache  and did not turn up any finds so I put the statement at end of file. Then restarted squid, checked systemctl status and tested with browser. It seems to be running fine. Thank you agin. I will mark this post as solved.